# Two php-fpm processes running after trying to update php version. Wordpress using the wrong one

Tags: php, update

I am currently running a Debian server on Google Cloud Compute.

`Linux host1.example.com 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I installed PHP 7.3, however in WordPress it still says that I am using version 7.0. I have also seen that there are two different versions running.

```
root      3163     1  0 13:31 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  3165  3163  0 13:31 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  3166  3163  0 13:31 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
laurins+  3269   889  0 13:33 pts/0    00:00:00 grep php
root     24713     1  0 13:11 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 24714 24713  0 13:11 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 24715 24713  0 13:11 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Is it safe if I simply kill the 7.0 process? Also, did I do something incorrectly during the installation process?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the previous version with:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
```

worked